# Regex for lines containing one string and not containing another string

Tags: javascript, regex, editor, pcre

I have following regex handy to match all the lines containing `console.log()` or `alert()` function in any javascript file opened in the editor supporting PCRE.

```
^.*\b(console\.log|alert)\b.*$
```

But I encounter many files containing `window.alert()` lines for alerting important messages, I don't want to remove/replace them.

So the question how to regex-match (single line regex without need to run frequently) all the lines containing `console.log()` and `alert()` but not containing word `window`. Also how to escape round brackets(parenthesis) which are unescapable by `\`, to make them part of string literal ?

I tried following regex but in vain:

```
^.*\b(console\.log|alert)((?!window).)*\b.*$
```

Comment: what happens if both of them is not there? is it mandatory that one should be present and other absent?

Comment: If both strings aren't there then no match as it is not the line I want to replce/remove, If `window` and `alert` are both in same line like `window.alert()` then it should not match so `alert` or console should be there but in same line `window` shoudn't be present. In short only match lines having `alert()` or `console.log()` and not having `window`.

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean by this: _"how to escape round brackets(parenthesis) which are unescapable by \, to make them part of string literal"_? What exactly do you need? There is no need to escape `(` and `)` in strings and you can escape them using a backslash in regexes.

Comment: I tried to match exactly `alert(` in this same regex by `^(?!.*window\.).*\b(console\.log|alert\()\b.*$`, but as you can see here in demo link, it doesn't work. http://regexr.com/3dfls

Comment: remove `\b` from last `^(?!.*window\.).*\b(console\.log|alert\().*$`

Comment: unsafe in what sense? security wise or efficiency wise?

Comment: can't say much about security..but there will be no issue of efficiency unless the file is very very huge in GB's (or TB's)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a negative lookhead, like this:

```
^(?!.*window\.).*\b(console\.log|alert)\b.*$
```

The negative lookhead will assert that it is impossible to match if the string `window.` is present.

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fN4iJ7/1)

As for the parenthesis, you can escape them with backslashes, but because you have a word boundary character, it will not match if you put the escaped parenthesis, because they are not word characters.

> The metacharacter \b is an anchor like the caret and the dollar sign.
>   It matches at a position that is called a "word boundary". This match
>   is zero-length.
>
> There are three different positions that qualify as word boundaries:
>
> - Before the first character in the string, if the first character is a
>     word character.
> - After the last character in the string, if the last
>     character is a word character.
> - Between two characters in the string,
>     where one is a word character and the other is not a word character.

Comment: Thanks for answer, it works, can you answer my sub-question, in what situation does parenthesis cannot be escaped by a backward slash, and how should I escape them in those situations ?

Comment: They can be escape with backslash, but because you have a word boundary character, it will not match if you put the escaped paren. You will have to remove the second word boundary.

Comment: So I have to mandatorily remove the word boundary character ?

Comment: If you want to match the parens inside the capture group, yes.